# Select the Value of custom OrderBy in Linq Query

Tags: linq, asp.net-core

I have to group the data by model number, get the sum of the grouped items, and do a custom sort. I'm having problems returning the value of "type", which is the sort order.

I've tried a number of different things, this is where I'm at right now.

type = x.type is not correct.

Sample Request Data:

```
[
  {
    "type": "ANTENNA MAKE - MODEL",
    "sector": "F",
    "position": "7",
    "qty": "3",
    "model": "NNH4-65D-R6"
  },
  {
    "type": "ANTENNA MAKE - MODEL",
    "sector": "A",
    "position": "1",
    "qty": "3",
    "model": "NNH4-65D-R6"
  },
  {
    "type": "RRH - WCS band",
    "sector": "B",
    "position": "1",
    "qty": "1",
    "model": "B2/B66A 8843"
  },
  {
    "type": "RRH - WCS band",
    "sector": "B",
    "position": "1",
    "qty": "3",
    "model": "B2/B66A 8843"
  }
]
```

Query

```
var ModelList = current.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.model) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.type))
    .OrderBy(x => x.type == "ANTENNA MAKE - MODEL" ? 1 :
                    x.type == "Antenna RET Motor" ? 2 :
                    x.type == "SURGE ARRESTOR" ? 3 :
                    x.type == "DIPLEXER" ? 4 :
                    x.type == "DUPLEXER" ? 5 :
                    x.type == "Antenna RET CONTROL UNIT" ? 6 :
                    x.type == "TMA/LNA" ? 7 :
                    x.type == "CURRENT INJECTORS FOR TMA" ? 8 :
                    x.type == "PDU FOR TMAS" ? 9 :
                    x.type == "FILTER" ? 10 :
                    x.type == "SQUID" ? 11 :
                    x.type == "RRH - 700 band" ? 12 :
                    x.type == "RRH - 850 band" ? 13 :
                    x.type == "RRH - 1900 band" ? 14 :
                    x.type == "RRH - AWS band" ? 15 :
                    x.type == "RRH - WCS band" ? 16 :
                    x.type == "Additional RRH #1 - any band" ? 17 :
                    x.type == "Additional RRH #2 - any band" ? 18 :
                    x.type == "Additional Component 1" ? 19 :
                    x.type == "Additional Component 2" ? 20 :
                    x.type == "Additional Component 3" ? 21 :
                    x.type == "DC TRUNK" ? 22 :
                    x.type == "DC BLOCK" ? 23 : 23)
    .GroupBy(x => x.model)
    .Select(x => new {
        model = x.Key,
        type = x.type,
        qty = x.Sum(y => y.qty),
        elev = x.Average(z => z.elev)
    }).ToList();
```

In this example I expect to receive the following:

```
[
  {
  "model": "NNH4-65D-R6",
  "type": "ANTENNA MAKE - MODEL",
  "qty": 6,
  "elev": null
  }
  {
  "model": "B2/B66A 8843",
  "type": "RRH - WCS band",
  "qty": 4,
  "elev": null
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adjust your select like this:

```
.Select(x => new {
    model = x.Key,
    type = x.Select(y => y.type).First(),
    qty = x.Sum(y => y.qty),
    elev = x.Average(z => z.elev)
}).ToList();
```

Comment: Awesome, that did it!